# Where is SWT lib in Eclipse neon?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-neon

I downloaded the Neon version of Eclipse, but all the normal libs in plugin folder are not there (in particular, i need SWT). Where can I find them?

Comment: They are all in the normal places. What platform is this (Mac, Linux, Windows, ....)? Also note that SWT can be downloaded separately.

Comment: It is windows. But I cannot find it. Is there any problems if previous version of eclipse used to be installed (now deleted)

Comment: It would not run at all if there was no SWT. If you used the installer version rather than the old style 'package' install then I think the 'oomph' installer does use a new location. I don't use that style install so I'm not sure where it puts things. You can SWT on its own from the [Eclipse Project](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) download site.